# Bluetooth pairing without pin code

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am a newbie working on bluetooth, and I would like to get some advice regarding the pairing process. I have googled this but I did not find much information ...

My goal is simple: I want to do a pairing to a headset without entering a pin. I have an android (nexus S running Android 4.1.2) and an iphone (3GS running ios 6.1.3).
If I connect to a device like a Jabra BT3030 (bluetooth headset), the pairing is performed without asking me any pin code.
Now I want to do the same from an Ubuntu (with BlueZ 4.6), i.e. I fake a bluetooth headset by enable only the correct service and so on. I disabled the authentication.
When I pair my iphone to this device, no pin code is required (as expected), but when I connect from my Android device, it still asks me for a pin code, whereas I would expect to have the same behavior than with the Jabra.

Would you have any idea of what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Guillaume

Comment: Hi pingguo, you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Android Uses UUID for pairing and connection for two devices...for two devices conneting, one device should send request and one should accept and for both UUID should be same...

Like also used bluetooth there I need to intall my android app to both the devices then only I can pair the two devices...because only that app is knowing the UUID. and for iPhone it may be different so if from the native code of iOS u can know the UUID ur android device can be paired through app...

Answer (score 0):

The Standard password for a Jabra BT3030 is 0000. Many other bluetooth devices have a standard password. For the Case a system only accepts devices with passwords, and u cant enter a pasword on a device without keys :D

Maybe the solution is implementing the standard passwords for mutliple devices and use them instead f forcing a connection without password.